# Error using AFFTDN to clean audio file in FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to clean up an audio file which contains background noise using the AFFTDN filter with a noise type of white noise.

I have not been able to find an example of the AFFTDN filter implemented and working.  Based on other examples I tried this command line code.

```
ffmpeg -i  C:\Media\test.wav afftdn="'nt=w':om='o'" C:\media\test_clean.wav
```

When I run this:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for afftdn="'nt=w':om='o'": Invalid argument.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your quoting is incorrect and you are missing `-af` to tell it that you are using an audio filter:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Media\test.wav -af "afftdn=nt=w:om=o" C:\media\test_clean.wav
```

Although according to the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afftdn) these are the default values, so you can simply just use `afftdn`:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Media\test.wav -af afftdn C:\media\test_clean.wav
```